# Socket timeout exception encountered when app is scheduled from crontab but when executed in interactive shell

Tags: cron, timeout

Environment: RH Linux, bash

I have been using this 3rd party tool (Java based) that allows me to make JMX calls to the application I'm managing.  It allows me to perform maintenance tasks on the application, do monitoring, etc...

As long as I'm testing the tool **manually in an interactive shell** it is working perfectly fine.  There is even this one maintenance job which takes around 3h50m to finish.  All the while of course I get no prompt back (because I didn't use nohup).  Also, when putting the command to launch the Java based tool with all the required arguments in a little wrapper bash script, it works fine.  It will do the work and output correct results/status on stdout when it finishes (after almost 4 hours).

However, I wanted to automate this maintenance job to run weekly so I put the little wrapper script in a cron job.  The wrapper script launches fine and the Java tool within also launches fine, the Java app (not the script!) exits with a **timeout SocketException** error after some 2h22 minutes (the number of minutes ranges from 20 to 23).

I have other crontab scheduled maintenance jobs using the same Java tool + wrapper script combo that are running fine all the time, but nothing that is required to run for such a long time.  So it is not an issue with the backend application or the tool/scripts, because it works when using the web-based JMX interface of the application and when using an interactive shell and for jobs that take less time.

As an extra test, I had the wrapper script launch the Java based tool using nohup in the background, but it still times out.